# Как сделать точные копии символов кнопок Windows 10?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-10

Использую такие номера но кнопки отличаются от Windows 10

xE739 слишком жирный

```
<!-- Maximize -->
<TextBlock Text="Value="&#xE739;" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/#Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" />
```

xE106 длиннее чем в windows 10

```
<!-- Close -->[
<TextBlock Text="Value="&#xE106;" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/#Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" />
```

нужно чтобы было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleW10" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template"  >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Margin="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"  Property="Background" Value="#444444"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: нарисуй сам  и все делов та

Comment: Очень странная у вас задача. Обычно, если нужны системные кнопки и все, что с ними связано - просто не убирают рамку окна, либо кастомизируют ее. Если же рамка стандартная убирается, то уже реализуется собственный дизайн, рисуются свои элементы, свои кнопки и т.д. Так вопрос, чем вас не устроила тогда стандартная рамка с кнопками системными?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось нужно размер шрифта поменять. при размере 10 смотрится по другому, более тонкие рамки

```
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Height="40" Width="40" Background="#0C0C0E">
                    <Line X1="5" Y1="20" X2="35" Y2="20" Stroke="Wheat" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid Height="40" Width="40" Background="#0C0C0E">
                    <Border 
                        Width="20" 
                        Height="20"
                        BorderBrush="Wheat"
                        BorderThickness="1" Margin="7,0,0,7"></Border>
                    <Border 
                        Width="20" 
                        Height="20" 
                        BorderBrush="Wheat" 
                        BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid Background="#0C0C0E"></Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Height="40" Width="40" Background="#0C0C0E">
                    <Line X1="5" Y1="35" X2="35" Y2="5" Stroke="Wheat" />
                    <Line X1="35" Y1="35" X2="5" Y2="5" Stroke="Wheat" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

[image: как то так]